# dynamic linkedlist, having trouble linking

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, linked-list

I am trying to add a struct to an already created node with a pointer. The problem is that i'm not linking them correctly. I was hoping someone could help me. The parameters are correct, one is the struct and the other one is a string that is going to go inside my newly created struct that connects with struct s.

(node s)--->(new node)-->null
I tried to call fileInsert() and  when i try to see the data in my new node, it is still null. filenames is the struct node pointer to link node s and my new node. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
void fileInsert(struct node *s, char *filename){
struct node *current=s->filenames;
while(current!=NULL){

    current=current->filenames;
}
struct node* f=NULL;
f=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
strcpy(f->data, filename);
current=f;
f->filenames=NULL;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting infinite loop?

Comment: I remember doing the same homework assignment! :)

Comment: edited my code, still not sure where i'm going wrong with this : /

I never enter the while loop to begin with. The first time it is null and because it does not link the nodes properly, the second time is null as well so again it does not enter the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to do this.

One, is to make the new node the beginning of your list:

```
struct node* fileInsert(struct node *s, char *filename) {
    struct node *current=s;

    struct node* f=NULL;
    f=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(f->data, filename);
    f->filenames=current;
    return f;
}
```

The other is to append it to the current list, which is sorta what you might be trying to do.

```
struct node* fileInsert(struct node *s, char *filename) {
    struct node *current=s;

    if (current != null) {
        while(current->filenames!=NULL){ 
            current=current->filenames;
        }
    }
    struct node* f=NULL;
    f=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(f->data, filename);
    f->filenames=NULL;
    if (current == null) {
        current = f;
    } else {
        current->filenames = f;
    }
    return current;
}
```

The first one simply creates a new node, and then points to current, adding it to the front. This works if current is a node, or null.

The second one checks if the list exists at all, if it does, it goes to the end of the list (by looking for a null pointer in filenames) and adds the new node, and if not it will make the new node the root node

Both routines return the beginning of the list.

Comment: The second one is what i was trying to accomplish. But why do you do current->filenames=f; in the if/else statement? didn't we set current to point to the last thing already "current->filenames" in our while statement?

Comment: By the time you get down to the IF statement, current is pointing to the node at the end of the list (since current->filenames == NULL). So, in the IF, we set filenames to the new node, which adds the node to the list. The new node, f, is the new end of the list, since its filenames == NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a *local* variable 'current' some value several times, then your function exits and you loose that variable forever. What you need to do instead is find last populated member and assign a value to its member *filenames*, pointing to newly allocated structure.

Comment: but doesn't it point to what my "root" s->filenames points to? so if i set current=f;, doesnt that make s->filenames point to f?

Comment: Nope, current=f just changes the value of current to f. Both are pointers, so you change value of one pointer with value of another pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop to

```
while ( current != null && current->filename != null)
```

Whats happening is current becomes null but null is address 0x0 so youre not linking anythinf. You want to stop at the last non null node

EDIT: picture it like this

```
NODE1 -> NODE2 -> NODE3 -> NULL
     ^ current
```

As you traverse your loop whats happening is

```
NODE1 -> NODE2 -> NODE3 -> NULL
         ^ current
```

...

```
NODE1 -> NODE2 -> NODE3 -> NULL
                                                 ^ current
```

Current is a memory address thats not really tangible. No physical meaning. You lose all iinformatin about node1 to node3 when you reaxh NULL

When you add the node you get this

```
NODE1 -> NODE2 -> NODE3 -> NULL

NODE4->NULL
```

both exist in memory but not connected

Sorry for bad formatting im on my phone

Comment: but  current is a pointer so it points to null and i am doing current=f; so current should be pointing to our newly created node no?

Comment: yes but nothing points to your new node because you lost it once you reached null

Comment: but.. i don't understand. current in the end is just the last struct node of s->filenames in the linkedlist.

Comment: Yes but nothing poimts to it. You lose information about it and youre left with the new node

Comment: nothing points to it at that time but that's why i try to do current=f; now current which is really a struct pointer in node3 points to f, my new node.

Comment: No because yoir loop made current NULL. So node3 is lost

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why. At the end of the loop isn't current just pointing to the same thing that the struct node down the linked-list is pointing to? So as we loop we are traversing until that pointer does not point to another node. But then we make that pointer point to another node by making it point to the newly created node.